# Is it true that $ \sup_x (f(x) - g(x)) \geq \sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x)? $

Tags: real-analysis

For a set $X$ and $f, g \in \mathbb{R}^X$, is it true that
$$
\sup_x (f(x) - g(x)) 
\geq
\sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x)?
$$
Thanks.

Comment: Suppose first that $\sup_x f(x)$ and $\sup_x g(x)$ are attained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  Ask the (easier) question, how $\sup F+\sup G$ compares to $\sup(F+G)$.  Then let $F=f-g$ and $G=g$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup_x f(x)$ is achieved at $x=x^*$, 
$$
\sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x) \leq f(x^*) - g(x^*) \leq 
\sup_x (f(x) - g(x)) 
$$

If $\sup_x f(x)$ is not achievable, ...?

Comment: Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we choose an $x_\varepsilon$ with $f(x_\varepsilon) > \sup_x f(x) - \varepsilon$, and ... [of course, if $f$ and $g$ are both unbounded from above, the inequality doesn't make sense ($+\infty - (+\infty)$)].